# Why can't find file when use `use_frameworks!` pattern？

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have a pod library called 'A' which write by `swift`. This library has a 'subspec' called 'B'. 'B' depend on another library called `BSDK` which write by `OC`. `BSDK` include a `B.framework` and a `B_Bridging_Header` file. `B.framework`'s headers are include three `.h` files. That three `.h` files imported in the `B_Bridging_Header`. When I use  'A' through the pattern `use_modular_headers!`, it will be ok. But when use the pattern `use_frameworks!`, the `B_Bridging_Header` will occur an error can't find this three `.h` files:

```
Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'A.B_Bridging_Header': '/Users/*/Desktop/*/Pods/BSDK/BSDK/frame/B.framework/Headers/*.h'
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by adding an `Modules` folder into `B.framework`. This folder contains a file called `module.modulemap`. This file write likes below:

```
framework module B {
    header "One.h"
    header "Two.h"
    header "Three.h"
    
    export *
}
```

So I can import this framework by module.